# .htaccess RewriteCond QUERY_STRING leads to 404

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to display a coming-soon page to all visitors of a website. 
But for testing purposes I would like to show the real website if a certain query-string is added to the URL.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)backdoor=1($|&)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !coming-soon
RewriteRule ^.*$ /coming-soon.html [L]
```

Test Cases:

1. Loading the website **without** the block above in my htaccess file
   works (with and without backdoor=1).
2. Loading the website **with** the block above shows the coming-soon.html content
3. Loading the website with the block above and with "?backdoor=1" parameter **shows a 404 error**.

**UPDATE:**

I have found out that all PHP files fail with the script above. Static files work:

```
/test.php --> coming-soon.html
/test.php?backdoor=1 --> 404

/test.txt --> coming-soon.html
/test.txt?backdoor=1 --> shows the content of the file correctly
```

Furthermore I have found out that if I do not use the QUERY_STRING condition but REMOTE_ADDR everything works (but I still would like to check for the querystring, not for the IP):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !123.123.123.123$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !coming-soon
RewriteRule ^.*$ /coming-soon.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this rule:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)backdoor=1($|&) [NC]
RewriteRule !^coming-soon\.html$ coming-soon.html? [L,NC]
```

`?` in target will strip off `?backdoor=1` after rewrite so that rewritten URI is just `/coming-soon.html` (without query string).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately the result is the same like with my code. I have even removed anything else from the file - but still the same behaviour

Comment: Can you please post your full .htaccess in question. Also can you tell me an example URL which is generating 404?

Comment: I am just using your 4 lines. All PHP files show a 404 - all other files work (for example /test.php is not found, while /test.txt is returned correctly).

Comment: What iare your Apache and PHP versions?

Comment: PHP 7.1, Apache 2.4.28

Comment: so if you rename this .htaccess to something else then `/test.php?backdoor=1` starts working?

Comment: yes, without those lines (or without the htaccess at all) it works.

Comment: Very strange. Is it possible for you to turn on `RewriteLog` in Apache and paste log messages here in question?

Answer (score 0):

I decided 10 years ago that redirects at the server level were WAY too much work. In addition to that, they are hard to log and hard to test.

Since this is temporary, why not do this directly at the app level? Just write a simple if/then statement in your php?